# What is clump Sort?

Tags: sorting

I have heard that `Clump sort` is an alternative of `Heap sort`. I did not find much about on Internet. Here clumps of numbers are either ascending or descending order in input.

for Example...

`2 5 8 25 40 30 20 65  83`

Here 3 clums are as

`2 5 8 25 40`

`30`

`20 65 83`

What is most efficient way to implement it? why do we need it in first place?

Comment: There's an IEEE paper on it, but I don't know if it's available to the public (I get it through my campus). It says it's for sorting medical data.

Comment: yaa, I read it in another post on stackoverflow, but i wanna know how it is implemented and why we need this for medical data only?